# Did the bodachs know Odd could see them?

Tags: plot-explanation, odd-thomas

In [Odd Thomas (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1767354/) we see early on when we're introduced to the bodachs that if they know you can see them, they'll kill you. Throughout the movie, we see Odd trying to avoid looking at the bodachs, but toward the end (in the mall) he suggests that the bodachs were using him. We also see in various scenes where it looks as if the lead bodach is suspicious of Odd.

So are the bodachs aware of Odd being able to see them and if so, were they in fact using him instead of killing him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed bodachs know about the gift that Odd can see them. This is the main twist of the movie towards the end. Bodachs main motive and plan is to cause a disaster in the mall which would lead to hundreds of casualties.

The reason why Bodachs never went near the co-conspirators because Odd would find out that they're planning on a mass destruction.

Comment: That's what Odd mentions, but it was just his guess. It makes sense though when you consider that they didn't go near the co-conspirators.